# Magento 2: Home page image on Facebook

Tags: magento2, home, social

How do I specify what image is displayed on social media, like Facebook, for my home page if someone posts my home page URL on there?

Answer (score 3):

Go through below links, they might help you out.

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices
- http://ogp.me/

Basically you need to implement the OG tags on your page.

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite the theme's default head layout.xml with the OG:image facebook properties that it parses for the images it displays.

Very similar question, and your answer is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12109912/how-to-add-facebook-ogmeta-tags-in-layout-xml-in-magento